# Can a wireless router theoretically malfunctionally send out harmful frequencies?

Tags: router, wireless-router, antenna, defective-hardware

My router has started to malfunction softwarewise, is it possible that the wireless router antenna is transmitting out wrong frequency electromagnetic radiation which is harmful to myself or other electronic devices?

Comment: The range of frequencies that a wireless router can produce will never harm a person. If you don't believe me and the device is not working why not just unplug it?

Comment: What about electronics? Could you cite some trustworthy sources as well?

Comment: Same thing for electronics. Again, if you are so concerned why not just unplug it though?

Comment: I just ordered a new one. I will unplug it when the new one arrives.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  In the future, please include the symptoms and descriptions that make you think that the old one is more dangerous than the new one.  If the old one is making noises or heat, it's possible that it could catch fire.  Since you've already decided to unplug it, consider bringing it to an electronics recylcing place like Staples with the original power brick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, wireless routers are built to transmit a single watt max, and there aren't really any failure modes that would allow it to transmit with much more power, or with a much higher frequency, to where it would be harmful.

Remember that low power electromagnetic waves aren't harmful below ultraviolet frequencies, which start at 750 terahertz, so like 6 *orders of magnitude* higher frequency than Wi-Fi devices would put out, even when failing.

To put that in perspective, a typical incandescent night light like you may have had in your nursery as a baby is about 4 watts at visible light frequencies in the mid hundreds of terahertz. So if you're not afraid of a night light, you shouldn't be afraid of a Wi-Fi device which is 1/4th the power and 1/100,000th the frequency.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if it catches fire it can put out enough infrared radiation to cause you pain or discomfort at short range. But it can’t put out harmful radiation at radio wavelengths.

Comment: </sarcasm> Well done.